# replicating the same process without taking up more space

Tags: anylogic

I have a model with seize-delay-release-sink logic, but I need to replicate it 100 times. This is obviously very space consuming in the editor and a tedious task.

Any suggestions on how I can make 100 identical seize-delay-release-sink in a quicker and more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the blocks, right-click and select "Create flow chart block". Now, you can instantiate that a million times, if you like. See this [explanatory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Nu1a9Te6ac&t=307s&pp=ygUZYW55bG9naWMgZmxvdyBjaGFydCBibG9jaw%3D%3D) as well.

Comment: Cool, thanks. That was understandable